# Should I use CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO) when do a parallel call to another microservice?

Tags: spring, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Let's say we have a `getProducts()` method in a controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/products")
class ProductController(
 ...    
){
   suspend fun getProducts(): ProductsDto {
        val productsDtoRs = productService.getProducts()  (1) to get a response
        
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {        (2) no need to wait for response  
            subscriptionService.createSubscription()
        }         
        return productsDto 
   }
}
```

which makes two calls to another microservices: one to generate a response, and another one is just a call that we don't need to wait for, that's why we launch it in parallel.

Is there a need to use `Dispatchers.IO` thread in this case, if no CPU consuming operations are done in `subscriptionService.createSubscription()`? It's just a call to another microservice.
Or `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch` whould be enough?

And the second question. Are any memory leaks possible due this second call, should I free resources somehow here?

Answer (score 3):

You said there is no need to wait for `createSubscription()`. I think you should ask yourself a different question: if you need to NOT wait for it. Only because we don't use a result of a call to create a response, doesn't mean we shouldn't wait for it. What if `createSubscription()` fails? Is it safe to ignore the failure and don't even inform the caller about it or maybe we should propagate the error?

Of course, there are valid cases when we actually like to schedule an asynchronous task, but again - that should be a conscious decision according to the application requirements.

> Is there a need to use Dispatchers.IO thread in this case

Assuming `createSubscription()` is a suspend function as well and it is implemented correctly, it shouldn't matter that much which dispatcher we use. I suggest `Dispatchers.Default`. If it is not a suspend function and it is blocking then we should use `Dispatchers.IO`.

> Are any memory leaks possible due this second call, should I free resources somehow here?

No need to free any resources, however, we generally leak background tasks here. If for example due to some kind of a bug these tasks never complete, we won't know and the application will work normally, until tasks pile up and eat the whole memory. It is always a good idea to track background tasks - either by their caller or some kind of a service.

Also, it is generally discouraged to create fire-and-forget coroutine scopes as in your example. What you did is a convoluted way of saying `GlobalScope.launch {}`. Common pattern is to create a scope for your service and use it to launch its tasks. Having said that, if the service is a singleton that runs for the whole lifetime of the application, then it doesn't change much.

Comment: Thank you. If createSubscription() fails, errors are written in log, that's sufficient. Yes, createSubscription() is a suspend function.